# print(int and str) How does this work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just exploring the logic of python and the way it works..
I want to know how this code works and what it actually means that made it give these results..

code:

```
print(str and int)
print(int and str)
print(str or int)
print(int or str)
```

result:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779600/5858851).

Comment: `X and Y` is `Y if X else X` whereas `X or Y` is `X if X else Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) Python has "Truthy" and Falsey values, meaning objects are evaluated as True or False in the context of logical operations. For example, the following code prints out "Yay!"

```
if str:
    print("Yay!")
```

Same if you replace `str` with `int`

ii) `and` terminates once a False assertion is encountered; `or` one a True assertion is encountered. Hence `and` returned the last expression and `or` returned the first expression in your case since both expressions evaluated to True independently.

Answer (score 2):

From the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

```
 - x or y    -->  if x is false, then y, else x
 - x and y   -->  if x is false, then x, else y
 - not x     -->  if x is false, then True, else False
```

This means that it returns the item itself not just True or False

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) it mentions:-

> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return
>   to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument.

So that is why `str or int` return `str` and `str and int` returns `int`

Answer (score 1):

Python uses following approach:

1. For "and" operator:

   - if left operand is true, then right operand is checked and returned.
   - if left operand is false, then it is returned.
2. For "or" operator:

   - if left operand is true, then it is returned.
   - if left operand is false, then right operand is returned.

In your case, `str`and `int` are classes and so evaluated as true, which fully explains what you observe.

Answer (score 0):

`and` gives you the last object on the last condition it checked to check if it's `true` or `false`, while `or` stops at the first one that passes. since both are `str` and `int` evaluates to `true` since they are defined objects, you get them accordingly

To prove and you can do :

```
print(str and int and bool) #<class bool>
```

And you are proving `or`.